# Status message thingworx

Tags: iot, thingworx, status-message

I create a ThingWorx Project,i use a message box,When a status message appears, it waits 7 seconds and then disappears, if during this time a new message come, status box shows new message and old message together.i want that,it always shows only the new message.

Comment: Impossible to answer without much more detail - provide the code you've written. [See how to ask a question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When a status message appears, it waits 7 seconds and then disappears, if during this time a new message come, status box shows new message and old message together.i want that,it always shows only the new message.

Answer (score 0):

Before thingworx 8.3 you can use JQuery and somehow hide that message but you cannot use JQuery for new versions. You can refer to Create An Extension for Thingworx guide and try to edit extension.